# AWS Amplify: How to recreate manually deleted CloudFormation stacks

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-amplify

I built an Amplify sample application following [this](https://amplify-workshop.go-aws.com/) workshop.
Afterwards, I manually deleted CloudFormation stacks (from the AWS console - selected root stack and executed delete stack action) hoping that I can rebuild them using `amplify push`. Unfortunately, amplify reports no changes and do not rebuild stacks. Is there a way to force amplify to provision the resources?

Comment: Did you delete the resources (e.g. database table etc) or you changed the something on stack files? You can elaborate *deletion of CloudFormation stacks*.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I edited my question. I deleted the root stack from the console. As far as I can see all the resources (DynamoDB tables, ElasticSearch, etc) are gone outside of S3 buckets which are still present.

Comment: Your case look parallel to the issue here: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/549 . If you agree, you may need `amplify init` and copy the former `amplify/#current-cloud-backend` to the newly created `backend` file.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the issue on github. Indeed looks like the same issue. Unfortunately, the suggested solution doesn't work. It's also a bit unclear in which project should I attempt `amplify push`. Regardless it throws an error in the old project and detects no changes in the new one. I will try to further clarify on the thread you suggested. Thanks again!

Answer (score 9):

amplify cli checks diff between `amplify/#current-cloud-backend` and `amplify/backend` folder inside your project. It doesn't check what is currently deployed in the cloud.

Since you have deleted the root stack, even if there were any changes to push, it would fail as the stack is missing. To recover from this error you can run `amplify init` and and when asked `Do you want to use an existing environment?` select `No`. This will recreate the root stack and will allow you to push your changes.

*PS*: Multi environment support is available in amplify cli version 1 and above. If its pre `v1` init command won't work

Comment: Thanks for your post. I understand that I need to run `amplify init` inside the app folder. When asked should I provide the same name of the environment or something different? I am running version 1.1.7 so that should be okay.

Comment: You could provide the same name if you want. The environment name needs is used only with in the projects `amplify/team-provider-info.json` file. Make sure you delete `<proj-root>/amplify` folder before running init

Comment: Thanks again Yathi. I have deleted the `/amplify` folder that was containing `#current-cloud-backend` and `backend` folders. Then inside of the root of my app directory, I have run `amplify init` and that successfully recreated the`/amplify` folder that I previously deleted. It has also created the root stack. Unfortunately after running `amplify init` I'm getting `No changes detected` message. I think I will give up on further attempts to salvage this project. Once again many thanks for your input!

Answer (score 3):

Amplify seems to keep information about what's hosted in AWS in `amplify/team-provider-info.json`. Inside this file should be JSON object with keys matching your environment names. If you leave your environment name's entry in this file and run `amplify init`, if you use the same environment name, you will most likely see a failure.

By removing the environment matching the one that you removed in AWS, amplify will forget about that environment's CloudFormation stack. Now you can run `amplify init` again, and use the same environment name, with success.

Answer (score 1):

If you delete a function or an API which other resources depend on, this could lead to the push to fail. So what I usually do, is to recreate the same function or API and push it again. It's a provisional hack I use, but I think there could be a better one.

Answer (score 0):

After many research i have found a solution

If you deleted backend manually. you can re-create it again by using this command

`amplify init --appId YOUR_APP_ID`

If you have access to the AWS console and can see the App ARN field (in general settings), you can find the AppId:

```
arn:aws:amplify:eu-west-1:xxxxxxxxxx/APPID
```

**Before initialising you have to delete [stacks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-console-delete-stack.html)**

After that just go with flow of amplify init, after that it will create backend and all as fresh start

And if you want to delete that app you can call `amplify delete` in cli it will delete from cloud and locally